# navigation drop down displays too far left

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I have been working on fixing this but cannot figure out what I am missing. I would like for drop down list to show right below its parent. The list shows but all go to far left and forces the remaining nav items to drop down to another line. i have included a snippet for what is currently looks like and an image of [what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWqf3.png).  Also, I have been trying to figure out how to add down fa fa-caret to nav items with drop down list. Please help!

```css
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(#9E0A0C, #EBEBEB);
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  /*float: left;  may need to be removed to show borders*/
  display: inline;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar li {
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar a:active {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*float: left;*/
}

.list {
  display: none;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #e7e7e7;
  background: #050243;
}

.list a {
  color: #000000;
  float: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background: #B6B6B6;
  columns: 2;
}

.list a:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.dropdown:hover .list {
  display: block;
}

form {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-image: url(pics/search.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Our Lodge</a>
      <div class="list">
        <a href="#">NEWS</a>
        <a href="#">FACILITIES</a>
        <a href="#">OFFICERS</a>
        <a href="#">GUEST BOOK</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
      <div class="list">
        <a href="#">CALENDAR</a>
        <a href="#">BINGO</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="list">
        <a href="#">BECOME AN ELK</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by first making the div.list element into an absolute positioned. The 'display:block' property was pushing all the other content down to the next row because the block element was taking up space.

As you see now the list is no longer pushing the content down but now it is not aligned to the correct nav item. We are also going to add a left:0 so that the div.list is to the left of the parent property.

Now the parent property needs a position of relative so that the left:0 on the child element is being positioned relative to the parent element.

```
.dropdown:hover .list {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
}

.navbar li {
   border-left: solid 2px #000000;
   display: inline;
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 800px;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but now the list is only showing the first li.  I believe I have to adjust the z-index.

Comment: What's missing in the li? which item?

Comment: The additional nav a elements I have in the ul are missing. These are drop down menus with at least two items. At this point, I have completely confused myself. I am still learning css and I have tried all of the options given and now I don' t know what to change to fix it. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your CSS code is, you missed to add `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to the `.dropdown` and `.list` selectors, which is compulsory to create dropdown. Try this code.

```
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(#9E0A0C, #EBEBEB);
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px #000000;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  /*float: left;  may need to be removed to show borders*/
  display: inline;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar li {
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar a:active {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar li:hover > a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /*float: left;*/
}

.list {
  display: none;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #e7e7e7;
  background: #050243;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.list a {
  color: #000000;
  float: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #B6B6B6;
  columns: 2;
}

.list a:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.dropdown:hover .list {
  display: block;
}

form {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-image: url(pics/search.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well but again, my full list is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

--> Please update following code in your existing file

```css
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(#9E0A0C, #EBEBEB);
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: solid 1px #000000;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.navbar li {
    border-left: solid 2px #000000;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar a:active {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.dropdown {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #e7e7e7;
    background: #050243;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.list a {
    color: #000000;
    float: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #dddddd;
    columns: 2;
}

.list a:hover {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.dropdown:hover .list {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

form {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

input {
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    background-image: url(pics/search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    background-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Our Lodge</a>
            <div class="list">
                <a href="#">NEWS</a>
                <a href="#">FACILITIES</a>
                <a href="#">OFFICERS</a>
                <a href="#">GUEST BOOK</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
            <div class="list">
                <a href="#">CALENDAR</a>
                <a href="#">BINGO</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
            <div class="list">
                <a href="#">BECOME AN ELK</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well but my full list is not showing. I have changed my following section to z-index:-1 but it's still not showing, any suggestions?